# Intellij Compound and Multirun plugin limitations and challenges

Tags: intellij-plugin

Recently we plan to move from eclipse to intellij because of performance issues. In eclipse, we had an option to run multiple run configurations using launch group. Similar plugins i found in intellij like Compound and Multirun. Compound is out of scope in our case which doesn't execute the run configuration in series instead starts in parallel. Multirun does but there is a specific constraint in it w.r.t time delay option.

I am looking for a plugin equivalent to launch group of eclipse to run multiple run configurations in a sequence order.